# Does custom URL or deep link to open Square app ios/android?

Tags: php, android, ios, square, pos

I already have link to pay charges from web app to square ios/android app

I learnt form [this link](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/building-web-based-points-of-sale-for-android-ios-9dfbc0f261e4)

but actually I am looking for link that open only square app via web button click

Like:

```
<a href="square://" >Open POS</a>
```

thank you for helping me adv.

Comment: Checkout `square-commerce-v1://`

Comment: @Satish for android?

Comment: @jaykumar-gondaliye - this should work for android too

Comment: @Satish nope its not working for android :(

Comment: i just try to set link like href=intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos;package=com.squareup;end" its open market place POS app